# xpath/xquery sql - Get all values

Tags: sql, xpath, xquery

Hi I have a blob of xml..

```
<string>1</string>
<string>2</string>
<string>3</string>
<string>4</string>
<string>11</string>
<string>1211</string>
<string>12331</string>
```

how would I get all the values using xpath/xquery in SQL

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xpath `//string` will return all the values in the intire xml the xpath `/string` will return only the values in the root node.

And for using it in sql look at this post [XPath to fetch SQL XML value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890923/xpath-to-fetch-sql-xml-value)

Answer (score 0):

in oracle database

you have `XMLType`  [(see this)](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96620/xdb04cre.htm) data type..

by this datatype you can get all the value..

all the examples are there itself, please go through that site.