# How to get all values in a list of objects with xpath?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

How can I get the name of all accounts with xpath?
The following expression does only return the first accounts name:

```
XPathExpression fax = xpath.compile("/accounts/account/name")

<accounts>
<account>
<name>Johndoe1<name>
<account>
<account>
<name>Johndoe2<name>
<account>
</account>
```

Comment: Same question was asked [here][1]! Take a look! 

[1]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7567845/xpath-xquery-sql-get-all-values

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to this tutorial : http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi/index.html you need to do something like this :

```
XPathExpression fax = xpath.compile("/accounts/account/name")
Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
    System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue()); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is the correct XPath expression, but the result you get depends on how you evaluate it.  The XPath expression `/accounts/account/name` returns a *node set* containing (in document order) all the `name` child elements of all the `account` elements under the `accounts` root element in the document.

In the XPath data model the string value of a node set is defined to be the string value of the *first* node in the set.  So if you use the single-argument `evaluate`:

```
fax.evaluate(someDocument)
```

this will evaluate the expression as a string and you'll just get the first `name` value.  Instead you need to evaluate the expression *as a node set*, then extract the string value of each node in turn, as suggested in [koopajah's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13721118/592139).

Answer (score 0):

Try with accounts//account, this will give you all the account tags within your document who's descendant is "accounts"